# "nuxt.options._layers is not iterable" error. What to do ? First day with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am totally new to vue.js and I got this error while trying to launch my first npm run dev :

> nuxt error : nuxt.options._layers is not iterable

I can't find any help about this anywhere. What to do ?
I created a codesandbox here :https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amapic/vuetest
Thanks

Comment: Your repro does not work. Also why are you using Nuxt2 (end of life, use Nuxt3). As a whole, why do you eve use with a meta-framework? Start slow and read VueJS' documentation for a few hours before using Nuxt.

Comment: It's because of chatgpt. It didn't tell me about Nuxt3

Comment: Don't expect things to be done well with ChatGPT.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the exact same error after going from node 16 to node 20 and having `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` being updated form v5.0.0 to v5.3.5.

```
FATAL  nuxt.options._layers is not iterable
 at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2409:32)
 at async setup (node_modules/@nuxtjs/tailwindcss/dist/module.mjs:92:7)
 at async ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2112:17)
 at async ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:167:20)
 at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:34:7)
 at async Nuxt._init (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:344:5)
```

I checked the Github repo (https://github.com/nuxt-modules/tailwindcss) and found out that v6 is available (6.11 already at time of writing).

So I switched to `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` v6 and this error was gone:

```bash
$ npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@^6
```

Answer (score 2):

just update tailwind-css to: npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@^6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the generated nuxt 2 project had a "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3", added automatically, and the error was thrown by one of its dependencies.

I downgraded this dependency to "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.0" and my project is running now.